# In the sin of two angles are equal, then proving that two angles are equal - w.r.t different traingles

Tags: trigonometry

From the text book:

[image]

What do they mean by:

`Therefore, AC/PR = AB/PQ`

?

Is the / division or ratio? What rule says that AC/PR = AB/PQ in this example?

What do I need to study to understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin(B)=\sin(Q)$ implies $\dfrac{AC}{AB}=\dfrac{PR}{PQ}$. Then recall the property $\dfrac ab=\dfrac cd \iff \dfrac ac =\dfrac bd $

Comment: which property is that? I am new to maths.

Comment: $\dfrac ab = \dfrac cd \iff \dfrac ab \cdot bd = \dfrac cd \cdot bd \iff  ad=cb$. Similarly $\dfrac ac = \dfrac bd \iff ad=bc$. Thus $\dfrac ab = \dfrac cd \iff \dfrac ac = \dfrac bd$

Comment: could you tell me which topic of maths should i study to know about the property you are talking about? . means multiply?

Comment: Try basic algebra i.e. pre-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

It's just multiplying both sides by $\frac{AB}{PR}$.